# Why is $(1+x)^2$ less accurate than $ (x+2)x+1$ for small $x$?

Tags: numerical-methods

I've known that accuracy is based on the amount of roundings (or multiplications) that occur, but from what I can tell, both equations will require the same amount.

My first thought was to related $(1+x)^2$ to $1+2x+x^2$ and say that there are two mandatory roundings that happen, but that equation is also equivalent to $(x+2)x+1$, so it wouldn't make sense to make my standard point off of that.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: $(1+x)^2$ requires two approximations, a sum and a multiplication.  $(x+2)x+1$ requires three, two sums and a multiplication.  Integer constants usually don't affect accuracy as significantly as non-$2^{-n}$ fractional numbers.  Have you read the Wikipedia article on interval arithmetic?

Comment: @abiessu are you saying (x+2)x+1 is actually less accurate?

Comment: Yes.  The primary reason is actually the number of times the approximated value $x$ is evaluated.

Comment: Note that interval arithmetic provides a way to prove the accuracy you can attain whereas otherwise all you have is examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's us assume that $x \approx 10^{-(n-k)}$, where $n$ is the number of significant digits remembered (in double arithmetic, this is roughly $16$) and $k$ is a small positive integer. Now, compare:

- $1+x$ has only $k$ significant digits from $x$.
- $x+2$ has only $k$ significant digits from $x$.

Not really different. But, lets go on:

- $(1+x)^2$ is a square of a number that has only $k$ significant digits from $x$, so only these $k$ digits matter.
- $(x+2)x$ is a number with only $k$ significant digits from $x$ multiplied by the whole $x$ (with multiplication, you don't lose significant digits), so the whole of $x$ matters (not completely, of course, but to a certain point; remember that a good part of it - $n-k$ digits - was lost in $x+2$).

Now, for the final "+1":

- $(x+2)x + 1$ has lost many digits again. However, if $(x+2)x - 2$ has more significant digits than $x$, (for example, if the first significant digit of $x$ is $4$ or more), than more of $x$ has survived.  More precisely, in that case, $k+1$ digits of $(x+2)x$ have survived, and this additional digit has *some* impact from $x$, as explained above.

As an example, here is some C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  double x = 0.000000000000654, t;
  t = 1+x;
  t *= t;
  printf("(1+x)^2  = %.16f\n", t);
  t = x+2;
  t *= x;
  t += 1;
  printf("(x+2)x+1 = %.16f\n", t);
  t = x*x;
  t += 2*x;
  t += 1;
  printf("x^2+2x+1 = %.16f\n", t);
  t = 1;
  t += 2*x;
  t += x*x;
  printf("1+2x+x^2 = %.16f\n", t);
  return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
(1+x)^2  = 1.0000000000013078
(x+2)x+1 = 1.0000000000013081
x^2+2x+1 = 1.0000000000013081
1+2x+x^2 = 1.0000000000013081
```

In Mathematica, computed with the $20$ digit precision:

```
x = 654/10^16;
N[(x + 1)^2, 20]
```

The result:

```
1.0000000000001308000
```

Note that $2 \cdot 654 = 1308$. Computed with the $33$ digit precision, the above yields

```
1.00000000000013080000000000427716
```

so we have obviously computed the $2x$ part with better precision in the last $3$ expressions (in my C code) than in the first one.

Comment: This is the direct computation method.  It will work exactly as advertised.  However, the accuracies shown can be improved by other methods.

Comment: @abiessu:  the issue wasn't to find the best way to calculate it, but to explain where the difference comes from.  I think this does it well.

Comment: @RossMillikan: I realize that the prevailing wind is against me on this one, right from the OPs question.  It's still important to consider ways of proving that one statement is more accurate than another vs. showing by example how they differ.  I know my own answer falls on the side of counter example instead of proof, but I can live with these facts and survive.

Comment: @abiessu I usually prefer formal proofs to stories, but when it comes to accuracy my feelings change. This is because proofs of accuracy are often very technical and tiring for the inexperienced reader. Please, don't get me wrong: I completely understand the need for them, but to explain *why* is some accuracy lower/higher than some other, I usually find that a story, like the one I wrote here, does a better job.

Comment: @vedran: I understand that.  I'm just attempting to point out for the benefit of the OP that there are methods available to prove accuracy, and that for at least the particular method I use the accuracy of the various forms of the equation is the exact opposite of his post and yours.

Answer (score 0):

A heuristic explanation: suppose that $x$ is very small; then the floating point approximation to $1+x$ will often be erroneous because of 'float rounding': for instance, suppose that you have 10 digits of core 'float' accuracy and that $x\approx 10^{-8}$; then $1+x$ will lose all but two digits of $x$'s accuracy, and when we square $1+x$ then the remaining digits stay lost.  By contrast, when adding $2+x$ we may lose another bit of accuracy initially, but the result is then multiplied by $x$ and this multiplication gains the 'full accuracy' of its second $x$ factor.

(On the other hand, the fact that $1$ is then added to the result leaves me skeptical, because much of that accuracy is promptly lost again; I would like this explanation much more if it were comparing e.g. $(x+2)x$ vs. $(x+1)^2-1$.)

Answer (score 0):

In interval arithmetic, this question is answered differently than you may expect.  In particular, the accuracy of every formula can be rigorously proven directly by evaluating increasingly small intervals up to the accuracy limit of the system.

Here is an example of how it works:

Given $x=[a,b]$ as the interval being evaluated with $a\lt b$, evaluate the following:

$$f_1(x)=(x+1)^2$$

$$f_2(x)=(x+2)x+1$$

$$f_3(x)=x^2+2x+1$$

$$f_1([a,b])=([a,b]+1)^2=[a+1,b+1]^2=[\min((a+1)^2,(b+1)^2),\max((a+1)^2,(b+1)^2)]$$

$$f_2([a,b])=([a,b]+2)[a,b]+1=[a+2,b+2][a,b]+1=[\min(a(a+2),a(b+2),b(a+2),b(b+2))+1,\max(a(a+2),a(b+2),b(a+2),b(b+2))+1]$$

$$f_3([a,b])=[a,b]^2+2[a,b]+1=[\min(a^2,b^2),\max(a^2,b^2)]+[2a,2b]+1=[\min(a^2,b^2)+2a+1,\max(a^2,b^2)+2b+1]$$

Given that we know only that $a\lt b$, $f_1$ and $f_3$ demonstrate the greatest similarity, but it should be obvious that if $|a|\gt|b|$ then $f_1\ne f_3$.  If we say that a measure of the accuracy is the ratio of the length of the input interval compared to the length of the output interval, then $f_1$ has greater accuracy than $f_3$ overall.

This isn't the best possible demonstration of how interval arithmetic works, but it should show how intervals can be used in evaluating functions.  In particular, it is clear that the accuracy is the opposite of that demonstrated in other answers here.